# Why can't I access files in S3 uploaded via PySpark?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have PySpark job that dumps a few datafile to my S3 bucket. I need to use these datafiles to build an ML model using AWS Sagemaker. But I'm not able to access these datafiles in S3 via sagemaker or boto3.

For example,

```
S3 address: 
s3://my-bucket-name/dataset/account_1/examples.csv
s3://my-bucket-name/dataset/account_2/examples.csv
...
...
```

I have multiple directories and files under the directory 'dataset' and all those files are required for sagemaker job. Sagemaker is using an AWS role that has S3FullAccess and if I create this 'examples.csv' manually, sagemaker job works perfectly fine.

PySpark command to dump this file to s3 is:

```
df.write.partitionBy(ACCOUNT_ID).csv("s3a://my-bucket-name/dataset", header=True, sep=";")
```

But my sagemaker job cannot access these files in S3 and result in the error as follows,

```
Error for Processing job sagemaker-scikit-learn-2020-05-09-08-32-50-724: Failed. Reason: ClientError: Failed to download data. 403 Forbidden (403): Forbidden
```

Even I try to download this file using Boto3 library, I get the same error. When I try to manually move this file on AWS console to some other directory, I still get the same error.

I believe, there is some problem in the way I dump this data to S3 and so its permissions are altered. Please let me know what is the issue here and how to resolve it?

Comment: Does PySpark write the files using same account as sagemaker and you manually are using?

Comment: Yes, S3 and Sagemaker services are in the same account. I'm using the same in both the ways.

Comment: Maybe worth inspecting the objects uploaded by spark. Check their ACL and compare to objects manually uploaded.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the mistake earlier. But pyspark is running in another AWS account than S3 bucket and Sagemaker. I tried to resolve this by doing sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3.canned.acl','BucketOwnerFullControl') in my pyspark code. But this doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Worked. Did this-> sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.acl.default','BucketOwnerFullControl')